# XML schema for QGIS symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, xml, microstation

I've been trying to import .cel files as symbology in QGIS. I was recommended to change those .cel files into .dxf, which I did. However, in order for the conversion from dxf to xml to work, I need the XML schema sample for QGIS symbology. I've exported existing QGIS symbology as an xml file. However, editing those exports to include the symbols I want to use, doesn't work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this schema doesn't exist. (Similarly, there is no schema for QGIS project files, which are XML as well.)

Comment: Thanks, so do you know of another way to import symbology that's now in dxf into QGIS?